# Left click not working on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: xorg

My mouse left click stop working after few mouse clicks. I have used certain commands in terminal to get it working but that doesn't work. Those commands are:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
metacity --replace
```

I am using Linux since last two weeks installed on my laptop. Before that I was booting it from PD. But the same problem is persisting in either way.

Answer (score 0):

None of the commands you issued will help with and intermittently or previously working mouse. I suspect a hardware issue. The four most likely problems are:

1. Dead battery. If you have a wireless mouse start with a fresh battery.
2. Bad Hub. If your mouse is not plugged directly into your pc, try plugging it in directly. Two related problems to check for are multiple buss powered hubs and lost power to powered hubs.
3. Bad mouse. Try a different mouse. Try unplugging and replugging the mouse.
4. Bad port. Try plugging the mouse into a different usb port.

Comment: But my external mouse works very good in Windows. and i don't have touchpad in my laptop.